# Unable to launch Chrome browser via Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

It seems as if there is a problem with ChromeDriver

**First attempt:**

```
Option Explicit
Private Chrome As New ChromeDriver
Sub ChromeAutomation()
    Chrome.Start: Chrome.Get "https://www.google.com/"
   
End Sub
```

**Second attempt:**

```
Option Explicit
Private obj As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub TestModule()
    Set obj = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    obj.Start
    obj.Get "https://www.google.com"
```

I have tried to uninstall and re-install Selenium and ChromeDriver, but I keep getting error **"Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)': Method 'Start' of object '_WebDriver' failed"**.  My reference libraries have been selected and I have no idea what else to try.  Please help

Comment: Please post your code and error messages themselves, not their pictures,

Comment: Try `obj.Start "chrome"`

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error using obj.Start "chrome"

Comment: I'm sorry. I cannot reproduce your error with the information you have provided using your code, running Microsoft 365 (Windows). Hopefully someon else will be able to assist you. What is your version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the version of Chrome you have installed.  Current version should be 114.0.something.  You need to have a corresponding version of Selenium installed. Visit this site to get the correct version of Selenium for Chrome and follow directions to install it in your PC: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads into
**c:\users\'you'\appdata\local\seleniumbasic**, or where ever your selenium is installed.

Comment: But the error message that I've always received states that explicitly. His error message does not.

Comment: Actually, you are right.  Looking at stuff I have done, I find that I don't even use the `start` method.  It may might not even be necessary.

Comment: I've installed SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0 and ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (My chrome is currently on Version 114.0.5735.199). ChromeDriver has been moved to the Seleniumbasic folder.  Still no luck on my end.